# How to get an about screen in your settings bundle in ios?

Tags: ios, settings.bundle

I have an easy question, though I'm not sure if it's doable or not:

How can I add an "about" page to my settings.bundle in iOS?

I have seen it done before. Just have a look at the facebook application settings. When you tap "about", you get an entire page full of text.

How is this done?

Are they relying on internal API perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called a 'Child Pane'- From [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH6-SW4);

"The child pane type lets the user navigate to a new page of preferences. You use this type to implement hierarchical preferences. For more information on how you configure and use this preference type, see “Hierarchical Preferences.”
The key for this type is PSChildPaneSpecifier."

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't that just embed a new hierarchical preferences view in your root preferences folder? The facebook-app about page opens a 10 page document with legal info. Not new preferences.

Comment: @Tovi7 Sorry, yes you are correct - I interpreted you question as just how to have a separate 'about' page, not how to have a document in it. However this article tells you how to do exactly what you are talking about; http://martinhicks.net/2012/04/how-to-create-license-section-in-ios-settings-app/

Comment: Oh ok. It's an overly complex solution, but it seems to be the only one. Fair enough. I'll accept it as my preferred answer.